# How to loop through an element and use the .split() element to remove the colons from the list shown?

Tags: python, list, loops

```
Scores = ["HW:65", "HW:75","Exam:95", "HW:90", "HW:95", "Exam:75"]
```

Tried to do a loop, but it doesn't work:

```
for Hw in Scores:
    x = Scores.split()
```

output should be something like:
Got 4 HW Scores: 65 75 90 95
The average HW Score: 81.25

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please adjust your formatting--it's difficult to tell what you are asking. I think you might want `[x.split(":") for x in scores]` or `[x.replace(":", "") for x in scores]`?

Comment: It should be `Hw.split()`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: output should be the following:
Got 4 HW Scores: 65 75 90 95
The average HW Score: 81.25

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use replace() and list comprehension:

```py
x = [score.replace(':', '') for score in Scores]
```

Another solution is to use translate() method and list comprehension:

```py
x = [score.translate({ord(i): None for i in ':'}) for score in Scores]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firts, u have to make list of the HW:

```
HWs = [(x.split(':')[1]) for x in Scores if "HW" in x]
# ['65', '75', '90', '95']
```

Cuz u wanna print all of the list, join and put in some variabel

```
total = ','.join(HWs)
```

To get the average, u have to convert from string value in list to integer. Put at new variabel. The, get the average with sum() and devided by leng of the new value. Last, print

```
myInt = [int(x) for x in HWs]
ave = sum(myInt)/len(myInt)
```

Here the full code:

```
Scores = ["HW:65", "HW:75","Exam:95", "HW:90", "HW:95", "Exam:75"]
HWs = [(x.split(':')[1]) for x in Scores if "HW" in x]
total = ','.join(HWs)
myInt = [int(x) for x in HWs]
ave = sum(myInt)/len(myInt)
print(f"Got {len(HWs)} HW Scores: {total} The average HW Score: {ave}")
```

Output

```
Got 4 HW Scores: 65,75,90,95 The average HW Score: 81.25
```